# Обновление данных datagridview без привязки к БД и таблицам c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

есть код заполнения DGV данным без привязки к БД и т.п.

```
        public int DGV3_FILL(string Cell_Name, int cout, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < dataGridView3.ColumnCount - 1; ii++)
        {
            for (int iii = 0; iii < dataGridView3.RowCount; iii++)
            {
                dataGridView3.Rows[iii].Cells[ii].Value = "";
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Cell_Name].Value == null) return cout+1;
        while (mass[i] != null) {
            if (mass[i].primaryKey == dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Cell_Name].Value.ToString()) {
                Regex reg = new Regex(@"^(.+)\/(\d+)");
                Match match = reg.Match(mass[i].identifier);
                dataGridView3.Rows[cout].Cells["Title"].Value = match.Groups[1].ToString();
                dataGridView3.Rows[cout].Cells["Level"].Value = match.Groups[2].ToString();
                dataGridView3.Rows[cout].Cells["ID"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value;
                if (mass[i].upgradeToArray != null)
                {
                    dataGridView3.Rows[cout].Cells["One"].Value = mass[i + 1].addr_1;
                    dataGridView3.Rows[cout].Cells["Two"].Value = mass[i + 1].addr_2;
                    dataGridView3.Rows[cout].Cells["Three"].Value = mass[i + 1].addr_3;
                    dataGridView3.Rows[cout].Cells["Duration"].Value = mass[i + 1].buildDuration;
                    if (mass[i].Amount != null && mass[i + 1].Amount != null) dataGridView3.Rows[cout].Cells["Low"].Value = (Int32.Parse(mass[i + 1].Amount) - Int32.Parse(mass[i].Amount)).ToString();
                }
                cout++;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return cout;
    }
```

в начале кода циклом пишу пустоту в ячейки DGV. Так вот DGV заполняется если только этот цикл за комментировать, иначе они остаются пустыми.

Comment: Вы заполняете датагрид пустотой, далее в цикле `while` сравниваете некий `primaryKey` с пустотой...

Comment: А, нет, у вас там разные датагриды. Выход из ситуации простой: гнать вас с работы за такие имена: `dataGridView1`, `dataGridView3`. Дайте _всем_ переменным _говорящие_ имена.

Comment: Хоть я слабо уловил логику кода, но меня смущает вот это место: `cout++; break;`, т.е. в случае успешного первого заполнения данными мы тут же вылетим из цикла, чёт я сомневаюсь, что это правильно. Да, и присоединяюсь к предыд. замечанию, у вас полный бардак с наименованиями: `dataGridView3` должен быть что-то типа `dataGridViewProducts`, `Cell_Name` - это же параметр метода, нафига его именовать с загл.буквы? Это же не класс и не метод! `mass[i]` - это приватное поле? Ну, так ставьте нижнее подчеркивание впереди названия `_mass[i]`, чтоб сразу отличать его от локальн. переменной метода.

Comment: И еще про читабельность вашего кода. Вы уж наконец определитесь с манерой расстановки фиг.скобок. Если вы любите открывающую скобку ставить в конце строки за объявлением метода или цикла, то вы уж следуете этой манере до конца, а то в одном `if` у вас так, а в следующем иначе, а потом хрен понять можно к какому `if` или циклу та или иная закрывающая скобка относится.